# How do I find the mode of an array by passing the pointer of that array to a function? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

So I'm totally new to pointers, I apologize for this, I'm supposed to pass an array of pointers and get the mode of that array.  After the array passes as a set of pointers, I can't manipulate the array to find the mode, everything I try results in a syntax error.

EDIT: I changed list to an array of pointers and I get a runtime error.

```
int main()
{
int size=0;
int *list[size];
cout<<"Please enter the size of your array: ";
cin>>size;
cout<<"\nPlease enter the numbers in your list seperated by spaces: ";
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    cin>>*list[i];
}
cout<<endl;


int mode=getMode(list,size);
cout<<"\n"<<mode<<endl;
return 0;
}

int getMode (int* list[], int arraySize)
{
    cout<<"The array you entered is listed below\n "<<list[0];
    for(int i=0;i<arraySize;i++)
        {cout<<setw(3)<<list[i];}
    int *number=list[0];
    int count1=0;
    int count2=0;
    int mode=0;
    for(int j=1;j<arraySize;j++)
        {
            for(int i=1;i<arraySize;i++)
                {
                    if(list[i]==number)
                        {
                            count1++; //counts the number of instances that the number occurs
                        }
                }
            if(count1>count2)
                {
                    mode= *list[j];
                    count2=count1;
                }
            count1=0;
        }
    return mode;
}
```

Comment: `list` is an array of integers, not an array of pointers.

Comment: When you pass an array to a function, it automatically decays to a pointer. You don't need to use `&list`.

Comment: when I try to make list into a regular array of int, and then pass it without the reference tag, the console tells me it cannot convert type int* into int** in the function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass an array to a function, it automatically decays to a pointer, so you don't need to use `&list`. And in the function, you shouldn't declare it `int *list[]`, it should just be `int list[]` or `int *list`.

Also, in the `getMode()` function, you need to count the matches of `list[j]`. You're just counting the repetitions of `number`, which is `list[0]`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int getMode (int list[], int arraySize)
{
    cout<<"The array you entered is listed below\n "<<list[0];
    for(int i=0;i<arraySize;i++)
        {cout<<setw(3)<<list[i];}
    int count1=0;
    int count2=0;
    int mode=0;
    for(int j=0;j<arraySize;j++)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<arraySize;i++)
                {
                    if(list[i]==list[j])
                        {
                            count1++; //counts the number of instances that the number occurs
                        }
                }
            if(count1>count2)
                {
                    mode= list[j];
                    count2=count1;
                }
            count1=0;
        }
    return mode;
}

int main()
{
    int size;
    int *list;
    cout<<"Please enter the size of your array: ";
    cin>>size;
    list=new int[size];
    cout<<"\nPlease enter the numbers in your list seperated by spaces: ";
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            cin>>list[i];
        }
    cout<<endl;

    int mode=getMode(list,size);
    cout<<"\n"<<mode<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/bDfNIy)

Comment: Thank you, Barmar, you've helped tremendously.  Is there any way I can mark this question answered?